# Suppose that a function $f: G \to H$ is an isomorphism? Must f inverse be an isomorphism as well?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

> Suppose that a function $f: G \to H$ is an isomorphism. Must $f$ inverse be an isomorphism as well? Prove it if it is so, else, provide a counterexample.

I think that it is, the following is my proof:

Since f is isomorphic, f is both bijective and homomorphic:

f is bijective implies that if s, t belongs to H, there exists a, b belongs to G such that $f(a) = s$ and $f(b) = t$. On top of that, $f^{-1} (s) = a$ and $f^{-1} (t) = b$.

f is homomorphic implies that $f(a \star b) = f(a) \circ f(b)$ which implies that $f(f^{-1}(s) \star f^{-1}(t)) = s \circ t$. Applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides, we have 
$f^{-1}(s) \star f^{-1}(t) = f^{-1} (s \circ t)$.

Hence, if s, t belongs to H, $f^{-1}(s) \star f^{-1}(t) = f^{-1} (s \circ t)$, which means $f^{-1}$ is homomorphic. Since $f^{-1}$ is also bijective, $f^{-1}$ is isomorphic.

Can someone verify if this is right. Thanks.

Comment: it is right. congrats.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof is correct. Well done!

As is customary for a [proof-verification](/questions/tagged/proof-verification) post, a little more feedback than a yes/no response is required. So, then, although clear (and English might not be your first language), your punctuation is a bit off and you neglected to use $\LaTeX$ for some of your symbols.